# Stacking Numpy arrays of different-sized images

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing

I'm creating an array of images using OpenCV for analysis in TensorFlow.

I've created the following function:

```
def files_to_img_array(path, files_list):
    '''
    Reads a list of image files and creates a Numpy array.
    '''
    # Instantiate arrays
    files = [path+file for file in files_list]
    img_array = np.zeros(72000000) # for flattened 4000x6000 images
    image_names = []

    for file in tqdm.tqdm(files_list):
        full_file = path+file
        image_names.append(file.split('.')[0])
        img = cv2.imread(full_file, 1)
        print(img.shape)
        img = img.flatten()
        
        img_array = np.vstack([img_array, img])
    img_array = img_array[1:] # remove instantiating zeroes
    return img_array
```

The problem is that the images are not uniformly sized:

```
 0%|                                     | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s](4000, 6000, 3)
 10%|███████▊                    | 1/10 [00:00<00:03,  2.64it/s](4000, 6000, 3)
 20%|███████████████▌            | 2/10 [00:00<00:03,  2.51it/s](2848, 4288, 3)
 20%|███████████████▌            | 2/10 [00:00<00:03,  2.18it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis
must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has
size 72000000 and the array at index 1 has size 36636672
```

I'm genuinely uncertain about how to approach this, both from a programming and image processing perspective. Does anyone have advice about how to either pad these differently-sized images, or if there is something in OpenCV that can handle this? (I'm happy to use PIL as well, I'm not married to OpenCV.)

Comment: I do not know any easy solution. What I have done in the past is check all the dimensions an find the max in each of width and height. Then pad the images with black or transparency to make them the same dimensions. You can use cv2.copyMakeBorder to pad your images.

Comment: `cv2` should have a `resize` method.  I think image resizing is better than padding, but your `tensorflow` docs (or other ML) should discuss that kind of issue.

Comment: @fmw42 I thought about doing that as well. The problem with that is that it throws off histogram analysis, so I can only imagine how it will wreak havoc with a classifier...

Comment: @Yehuda  OK. But you should have said that in your original question.

Comment: From the ML papers I have read, people typically resize images to a common size before passing them to an ML algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to stack arbitrary sized images vertically in Python/OpenCV with transparent padding.

Input Images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load images
img1 = cv2.imread("lena.jpg")
w1 = img1.shape[1]

img2 = cv2.imread("barn.jpg")
w2 = img2.shape[1]

img3 = cv2.imread("monet2.jpg")
w3 = img3.shape[1]

# get maximum width
ww = max(w1, w2, w3)

# pad images with transparency in width
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
img1 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1, 0, 0, 0, ww-w1, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0,0,0,0))
img2 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img2, 0, 0, 0, ww-w2, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0,0,0,0))
img3 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img3, 0, 0, 0, ww-w3, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0,0,0,0))

# stack images vertically
result = cv2.vconcat([img1, img2, img3])

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("image_stack.png", result)

cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer--I'm specifically trying to stack the Numpy array output of `cv2.imread()`, though.

Comment: I do not see why that is different. You put your images into a list. Rather than trying to stack in-line, you can loop over your list after reading them all. Or you can stack a new image onto the previous stack after checking the widths of the new image and previous stack. But I know little about Tensor flow and its requirements.

Comment: Cool! Basically, you made all the images the same size by padding?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @hpaulj for the comment in the question that led to my investigation and this answer.

The following code relies upon Keras and underlying PIL:

```
import PIL
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
import concurrent.futures

def keras_pipeline(file):
    TARGET_SIZE = (100,150)
    img = load_img(file, target_size=TARGET_SIZE)
    img_array = img_to_array(img)
    return img_array
 
def files_to_array(path, files_list):
    files = [path+file for file in files_list]
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        img_map = executor.map(keras_pipeline, files)
    return img_map
```

`keras_pipeline()` creates a transformation pipeline for each image. `files_to_array()` maps that transformation pipeline over each image and returns a generator. That generator can then be passed as a Numpy array using `np.hstack()`:

```
for img in img_map:
    existing_array = np.hstack([existing_array, img])
```